# How to store Integer inside of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, authentication

I am trying to write an login interface inside Java (Eclipse), and when the player logs in i would like to create an array that i am able to use like this:

Example:

```
int x = userX[username];
int y = userY[username];
```

And i want to be able to set it like this:
Example:

```
userX[username] = x;
userY[username] = y;
```

And since a players username can be anything (example: dark09.loser) i would like to be able to store integers inside of objects.
Thanks for help. (And sorry for bad english)

Comment: you want to use a string as an index? you'll want to look up HashMap. UPDATE: bmorris has written answer for this below

Comment: This is not clear. What are `userX` and `userY` arrays of? What is `username`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

map.put("username1", x);
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a `Map<String, Integer>`, then you can do something like this

```
final Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
final Integer x = myMap.get(username);
myMap.put(username, x);
```

Comment: FTFY: It's amazing how many problems can be solved with a `Map`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Hashtable<String,Integer>`, that should do what you want.

Comment: `HashTable` is synchronised and therefore slow. Map is better.

Comment: String is capitalized, and a primitiv type cannot be a generic type.